# Injecting default Maven project into other Maven components

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-mojo

I am developing a Maven plugin and I make use of the Assembly API to do some custom assembly construction. When my code runs, I get this stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.interpolation.AssemblyInterpolator.buildInterpolator(AssemblyInterpolator.java:177)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.interpolation.AssemblyExpressionEvaluator.(AssemblyExpressionEvaluator.java:44)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.DefaultAssemblyReader.mergeComponentsWithMainAssembly(DefaultAssemblyReader.java:470)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.DefaultAssemblyReader.readAssembly(DefaultAssemblyReader.java:390)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.DefaultAssemblyReader.addAssemblyFromDescriptor(DefaultAssemblyReader.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.DefaultAssemblyReader.readAssemblies(DefaultAssemblyReader.java:120)
```

From what I can tell, this is caused by `DefaultAssemblyReader` not having access to the default Maven project for the plugin. In my mojo, I have declared the Maven project and assembly reader like this:

```
@Component (role=org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject.class, hint="default")
protected MavenProject project;

@Component(role=org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.AssemblyReader.class, hint="default")
protected AssemblyReader defaultReader;
```

The AssemblyReader class doesn't have any setter to set the project on it, and I'm not sure how I can get `project` injected in to `defaultReader`. One solution I thought of would be to extend `SingleAssemblyMojo` and give it a setter for the project and pass *that* configuration object to the assembly reader, but that seems like a bit of a kludge. Is there a more elegant/proper way?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `@Requirement` instead of `@Component` there?